# DBAL: Pass extra connection options to pdo_pgsql

Tags: php, dbal

How do I pass extra connection options, like connect_timeout, keepalives, [etc..](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/libpq-connect.html) with DBAL?

Should it be passed as `driverOptions` or a pull request created for explicit support at `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOPgSql\Driver` ?

I tried passing via `driverOptions => ['connect_timeout' => 1]`, but not sure whether these settings are effective. When I do that with plain `pdo_connect` call:

```
$connectionString = 'host=... connect_timeout=1 keepalives=1 keepalives_idle=2 keepalives_interval=1 keepalives_count=2'
$connection = pg_connect($connectionString);
```

I know that these settings are at least applied because if I misspell any of those extra parameters an exception is raised:

```
$connectionString = 'host=... connection_timeout=1'
$connection = pg_connect($connectionString); 
PHP Warning:  pg_connect(): Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: invalid connection option "connection_timeout" in /troubleshoot/psql.php on line 18
```

And this exception is the way I check that this setting has been applied.

I do not get such error if I misspell configuration passed to DBAL though.

Comment: DBAL: doctrine/dbal 2.3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is not supported at the moment. All the extra options should be explicitly added to the [PDOPgSql/Driver.php](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOPgSql/Driver.php#L69).